# Remap key for adding multiple cursors in PhpStorm

Tags: ide, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

On VS Code I have the following keybinds.

`Shift` + `Ctrl` + `Up` to add a cursor above

`Shift` + `Ctrl` + `Down` to add a cursor below

How would I add this as a keybinding in PhpStorm. I don't seem to be able to find the current shortcut, which by default is:

> Press ⌥ twice, and then without releasing it, press up or down arrow keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those actions are called **Clone Caret Above / Below** and shortcuts can be set in `Settings/Preferences | Keymap`: use the search field there to narrow the list.

[image]